# Mock list size not incresae after adding mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I was developing the test case. Here I am using the Mock List and adding the mock objects inside it. But assetEquals always fails with error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :2
```

Here is my test case developed:

```
@Test
    public void Test() {
        MyClass ModelMock = mock(MyClass.class);
        final List<HashMap<String, Object>> listModelMock = mock(List.class);
        final Page currentPage = getMockedCurrentPage();
        final Page childPage1 = mock(Page.class);
        final Page childPage2 = mock(Page.class);
        Iterator<Page> mockIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
        HashMap<String, Object> object1HashMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Object> object2HashMap = new HashMap<>();
        when(currentPage.listChildren()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
        when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true);
        when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(childPage1);
        when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(childPage2);

        when(childPage1.getPath()).thenReturn("Test");
        when(childPage1.getTitle()).thenReturn("Title of Page1");
        object1HashMap.put("title", childPage1.getTitle());
        object1HashMap.put("src", childPage1.getPath());
        //Fail
        assertEquals(object1HashMap.get(0), "Title of Page1");

        when(childPage2.getPath()).thenReturn("Test");
        when(childPage2.getTitle()).thenReturn("Title of Page2");
        object2HashMap.put("title", childPage2.getTitle());
        object2HashMap.put("src", childPage2.getPath());

        listModelMock.add(object1HashMap);
        listModelMock.add(object2HashMap);
      // Fail   
        assertEquals(listModelMock.get(0).size(), 2);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, even object1HashMap.get(0) is null, Actual is Title of Page1

Answer (score 3):

Your listModelMock is a *mock* of a list.  You're not telling your mocking framework (presumable Mockito from what I can see) what to do on `add`.  So `add` does nothing.

From what I understand of your code, I don't think you really want to mock the list.  I think a real `ArrayList` would do the trick here.

Frankly, what is the class you are testing? It seems every object in your code is a mock.  There's no point in testing the mocking framework this way...

Nitpick: for an assert, the expected value comes first.  So `assertEquals(2, listModelMock.get(0).size(),2)`;